# Display Table Titles with a Table Model in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I would like to create a table with the constructor method JTable(TableModel). What exact methods in the TableModel do I need to display the titles of each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to embed your `JTable` within a `JScrollPane` and the column headings will be shown automatically:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(new JTable());
```

Comment: Thanks Adamski. There is however a small problem: I am using the GridBagLayout. when I add the JScrollPane with the JTable embedded to the container with this layout, the JTable is reduced to a very small size. I still did not manage to understand why....

Comment: Have you added the scrollpane with the appropriate fill, weightx and weighty values?

Comment: the values you need are fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH and weigthx and weighty values need to be relatively big in relation to the sum of theese values in their respective row/column.

Ideally weigthx  and weighty for the jscrollpane will be 1 (in base 1) and 0 in the rest of the components in the same row/column

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [TableModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) for example by extending the class [AbstractTableModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) or by to using a [DefaultTableModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).  This later has a [constructor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.lang.Object[][],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) where you can set the number and names of your columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the **getColumnName** method in the *TableModel* interface
to return the column names you want.

From the Javadoc of TableModel:

**String getColumnName(int columnIndex)**
Returns the name of the column at columnIndex. This is used to initialize the table's column header name.

**EDIT:**
The abstract class **AbstractTableModel** provides implementation for most of the methods in interface *TableModel* and also provides a default implementation for 
the **getColumnName** method in interface *TableModel* (but which might not suit your purpose as it returns column names as A,B..).

Create your own TableModel by subclassing **AbstractTableModel** and provide implemenation for the abstract methods and override **getColumnName** method. For example you can try something like:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   private List<String> rowData; // say 
   private List<String> columnNames; 

   MyTableModel(List<String> data,List<String> names) {
       rowData = data;
       columnNames = names;
   }

   // provide implementation of abstract methods
   public int getRowCount() {...}
   public int getColumnCount() {...} 
   public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {...}

   @Override
   public String getColumnName(int pCol) {
       return columnNames.get(pCol);
   }
   ...
}

// create your table as below;
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("Test");
data.add("Try");

List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<String>();
colNames.add("Name");

MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel(data,colNames);
JTable myTable = new JTable(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are really looking for the is the class [DefaultTableModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). Just read through the documentation and you will be on your own way.